# Online Server Detection with multiple arrays

Tags: php, loops, foreach, fsockopen

Heyo, putting together an online/offline detection page for our server cluster. I have managed to get the fsockopen portion working with the array, what I am trying to do now is to link them to second array to echo the specific server and port.

Really new to PHP here so be gentle on me! Been trying to merge the two arrays together without luck. It's obvious I am doing something wrong, just can't figure it out!

```
$server1 = 'x.x.x.x';
$port1 = [
11000,
11002,
11004,
];
$S1 = [
A1,
A2,
A3,
];

foreach ($port1 as $key => $port1) {
    $fp = @fsockopen($server1,$port1,$errno, $errstr);
    echo "Ping $server1:$port1 $S1 ==> ";
    if ($fp) {
   echo '<p style="color: green; text-align: left">
      "ONLINE"
      </p>';
} else{
   echo '<p style="color: red; text-align: left">
      $S1 OFFLINE
      </p>';
```

Comment: Sorry - not sure where your array `$S1` comes into this?  Also as the array values syntax isn't correct (needs quotes at least).

Comment: Sorry, I was missing the ]; at the end $port1, I was stripping down the code to be displayed for here and accidentally removed that one as well.

Comment: The $S1 array is to designate the grids(servers) running on those ports. So port 11000 is grid A1, etc. I need to keep the $port1 array seperate in order to use it in the fsockopen command but in the output echo I wanted it to display "Ping x.x.x.x:11000 A1" and the next would be "Ping x.x.x.x:11002 A2", etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If arrays `$port1` and `$S1` are in sync with each other, then you can use the key from your loop (`$key`) to get the value from the second array...

```
echo "Ping $server1:$port1 ".$S1[$key]." ==> ";
```

Comment: That was so simple and cannot believe I missed it. This worked perfect, just tested. Thanks a ton!